# How can I remove the background of a Bootstrap3 container?

Tags: html, css, styling

How can I remove the background color from a Bootstrap3 container?

I have tried to simply add the `rgba(0,0,0,0)` style to `<div class="container">`, but have yielded no success.

The container rows display a white background.

```css
.nobackground {
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="nobackground">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"> test text </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your code here

Comment: Absolutely.

HTML:
<html>
<body>
<div class="nobackground">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12"
    test text
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

CSS:
<style>.nobackground{rgba(0,0,0,0);}</style>

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to add new information rather than in the coments

Answer (score 0):

you need use `background` or `background-color` to change your background color

```
.nobackground {
    background-color: white;
}
```

or

```
.nobackground {
    background: white;
}
```